# Return two variables in ajax success function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How can I return BOTH the parcel number and the number of comments in one single function? I have two separate sql strings returning different results. I would like to be able to return both the apn number and put the value into a label and the count of how many comments there are. Is this possible? How do I do this?

Jquery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "classes/get-apn-count-comments.php?parcel_id=" + parcel_id,
    type: "GET",
    data: { parcel_id : parcel_id },
    dataType: 'json',
    error: function(SMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert("An error has occurred making the request: " + errorThrown);
    },
    success: function(data2){
        //do stuff here on success
        //$('#ParcelNumber').html(data[0]["apn"]);
        $('#ViewComments').val('View ' + data2[0].count + ' Comments');
    }
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
require_once('../config.php');

if(isset($_GET['parcel_id'])) {
    $db = new ezSQL_mysql(DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST);

    //get the apn based on id
    //$data = $db->get_results("select apn from parcels where parcel_id=" . $_GET['parcel_id']);
    //if($data != null) echo json_encode($data);

    //count number of comments for the id
    $data2 = $db->get_results("select count(*) as count from comments where parcel_id=" . $_GET['parcel_id']);
    echo json_encode($data2);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the php side create an array to hold both answer one and answer two. Then json_encode and echo the new multi-dimensional array exactly like you were with the old array.

Then on the javascript side in the callback run JSON.parse() to turn the array into a javascript object.

Example:

```
if(isset($_GET['parcel_id'])) {
  $db = new ezSQL_mysql(DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST);
  $return = array();
  //get the apn based on id
  $data = $db->get_results("select apn from parcels where parcel_id=" . $_GET['parcel_id']);
  if($data != null){
    $return['data_one'] = $data;   
  }

  //count number of comments for the id
  $data2 = $db->get_results("select count(*) as count from comments where parcel_id=" .$_GET['parcel_id']);
  if($data2 != null){
    $return['data_two'] = $data2;
  }
  echo json_encode($return);
}
```

js:

```
success: function(res){
    //do stuff here on success
    res = JSON.parse(res);
    console.log(res);
}
```

Comment: I'm now getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o"

Comment: That is probably some kind of syntax error. Could be there's a php error that is screwing up the markup the javascript is trying to read. So instead of getting <div>xyz</div> it's reading a php error message and jquery doesn't know how to parse it.